# CSS background image not showing up on rails site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, background-image

I'm trying to use the background-image css property with a website I'm building with Ruby on Rails.

I've tried several different variations of background-image: url, background: url, with and without quotations, and several paths to the image. The image is currently located in app/assets/images/upload.png.

```
background: url(upload.png);
```

**custom.css.scss**

```
/* UNIVERSAL */

body {
background-color: black;
padding-top: 8px;
width: 800px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
font-family: arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
}

.content {
background-color: white;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-khtml-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
padding: 1px 15px;
}

h2 {
font-size: 18px;
}

p {
font-size: 16px;
}   

ol {
font-size: 16px;
}


/* NAVIGATION */

ul {
padding: 0px;
}

#navtop {
float: right;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
bottom: 47px;
right:4px;
letter-spacing:1px;
}

#topnavcontainer {
margin-bottom: -40px;

}

#navtop li, #navbottom li, #navbuttons li {
display: inline;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}

#navbuttons {
word-spacing: 25px;
position: relative;
left: 400px;
bottom: 60px;
display: inline-block;
}

#navbottom {
text-align: center;
word-spacing:90px;
letter-spacing:1px;
margin-top:25px;
}

#navtop a:link, #navbottom a:link, #navtop a:visited, #navbottom a:visited  {
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 12px;
color: #999999;
}

#navtop a:hover, #navbottom a:hover {
color: white;
}

#uploadbutton a:link, #uploadbutton a:visited, #viewbutton a:link, #viewbutton a:visited  { 
text-decoration: none;
border-style:solid;
border-width:3px;
border-color:#666666;
padding: 5px;   
color: white;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: bold;
letter-spacing:2px;
}

#uploadbutton a:hover {
color: #FF0000;
}

#viewbutton a:hover {
color: #0066FF;
}   

/*style the main menu*/
.myMenu {
margin:0;
padding:0;
text-align: left;
}

.myMenu li {
list-style:none;
float:left;


}

.myMenu li a:link, .myMenu li a:visited {
display:block;
text-decoration:none;

padding: 0.5em 1em;
margin:0;


}

.myMenu li a:hover {
background-color:black; 
}

/*style the sub menu*/
.myMenu li ul {
position:absolute;
visibility:hidden;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

.myMenu li ul li {
display:inline;
float:none;
}

.myMenu li ul li a:link, .myMenu li ul li a:visited {
background-color:black;
width:55px;
}

.myMenu li ul li a:hover {
background-color:#999999;
}

/* HOME PAGE */

#homepage {
text-align: center;
}

#homeheadline {
color: white;
background-color: #333333;
font-weight:normal;
border-style:solid;
border-width:6px;
border-color:#333333;
letter-spacing:1px;
margin-bottom: 45px;
}

a#clickhere , a#clickhere:visited {
text-decoration: none;
color: #0066FF;
}

#videotitle {
color: #FF0000;
position: absolute;;
bottom: 70px;
display: inline;
font-size: 19px;
left: 60px;
}

#videolist {
position: absolute;
left: 40px;
display: inline-block;
}

#audiencetitle {
color: #0066FF;
position: absolute;
bottom: 70px;
left: 340px;
display: inline;
font-size: 19px;
}

#audiencelist {
position: absolute;
display: inline-block;
left: 320px;
}

a.greenbutton, a.greenbutton:visited, {
font-size: 14px;
color: white;
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration: none;
background-color: #009900;
border-style:solid;
border-width:7px;
border-color:#009900;
letter-spacing:1px;
}

#homead {
margin-bottom: 25px;
margin-top: 45px;
display: block;
}

#lists {
width: 538px;
height: 100px;
position: relative;
margin-bottom: 35px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
text-align: left;
}

/* FORMS */

.greenbutton {
font-family: arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
color: white;
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration: none;
background-color: #009900;
border-style:solid;
border-width:3px;
border-color:#009900;
letter-spacing:1px;
margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.textinput {
border: 1px solid #bbb;
height: 18px;
width: 300px;
margin-bottom:30px;
}

.signform {
text-align: center;
width:300px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;

}

.signformfields {
text-align: left;
}

#error_explanation {
color:#f00;
font-size: 16px;
ul { list-style: none;
   margin: 0 0 18px 0;
   }
}

.field_with_errors {
 @extend .control-group;
 @extend .error;
 }

/* Upload Menu */

#uploadpage {
height: 580px;

}
.uploadnav ul {
list-style-type: none;
}

.uploadnav {
width: 200px;
text-align: center;
float:left;


}

.uploadbox {
background-color: black;
background-image: url( image_path ("upload.png"));
border-style:solid;
border-width:25px;
border-color: black;
margin-top: 20px;

}

.uploadgreybox {
background-color: #CCCCCC;
border-style:solid;
border-width:25px;
border-color: #CCCCCC;
margin-top: 20px;
}

.uploadtext {
color: white;
background-color: black;
padding: 5px;
}

.uploadgreytext {
color: #666666;
background-color: #CCCCCC;
padding: 5px;
}



.uploadpagecontent {

float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The most correct way:

```
background-image: url(<%= asset_path 'upload.png' %>)
```

See the Guide for details: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets (sec. 2.2.1 CSS and ERB)

NOTE: If you're doing this in your application.css then add .erb extension to it to become application.css.erb

Comment: What path did Rails supply inside url()? Try to access it via http://localhost:3000/the_path

Comment: I can't understand this....I'm pretty new to rails so bear with me. I keep getting a syntax error now. I changed my "custom.css.scss" file to "custom.css.scss.erb". Since I posted in "background-image: url(<%= asset_path (/app/assets/images/upload.png) 'upload.png' %>)" I've been getting the syntax error. Is this the right path?

Comment: You didn't mention using SCSS. In this case use: `background-image: url(image_path('upload.png'));`. No need to change the extention here!

Comment: It worked for me: `background-image: url(image_path("upload.png"));`. I just removed spaces from your code.

Comment: Note that in Rails 7+ the recommended approach would be: `background-image: url('upload.png');`. Rails will automatically generate the correct URL and filename fingerprinting. This will even work in plain CSS files.

Answer (score 6):

if somebody comes by and still looking for an answer and you're using SASS and bootstrap, you can try

```
background: image-url('bgImage.jpg');
```

that worked for me. You can as well take a look on http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets as jdoe mentioned.

Comment: In case anyone views this answer in 2023 or beyond, note that SASS asset helpers such as image-url no longer work in Rails 7+ but the official Rails documentation (link above) hasn't been updated as of January 2023. Instead just use url() and Rails will automatically generate the correct URL and filename fingerprinting.

Answer (score 2):

You need to point to the image path correctly.  It should be:

```
background: url(/assets/url.png);
```

Try using the Inspector in Google Chrome - useful for checking resources like this that are called by CSS.

Comment: Note that in Rails 7+ the recommended approach would be: `background: url('myimage.png');`. If `/assets/` is included in the code, Rails will skip over the line and not generate a fingerprinted filename. Also Rails will automatically insert `/assets/`.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the similar problem and I found that the following code works

```
background-image: url('/assets/xyz.jpg');
```

Comment: Note that in Rails 7+ the recommended approach would be: `background-image: url('xyz.jpg');`. If `/assets/` is included in the code, Rails will skip over the line and not generate a fingerprinted filename. Also Rails will automatically insert `/assets/`.

Answer (score 0):

you probably need to change the path to the image. Where is the css file in relation to the images folder, eg app/assets/css/style.css.

If it is here then your path the the upload.png will be `background: url(../images/upload.png);` background: `url(/images/upload.png);` or `background: url(images/upload.png);`

Comment: @trickeedickee, The author says he uses assets folder, hence he MUST use pipeline-helpers for specifying paths for assets. Otherwise paths in styles won't be converted in production to use digest in their names.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to change the extention to your custom.css.scss or your importantly no  need to add erb to the scss file

in application.css file in your /assets/stylesheets directory
all you need is an element
html{
  background: url('/images/test.jpg');
  text-align:center;
  color:#fff;
}

Poss your css file, move the

Comment: I just posted my css file. any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

try

```
background: white;z-index:-1;
```